# Are these valid household circuit maps?

Tags: electrical, circuit

Is the wiring for these two separate circuits valid in the US?  If not, how so?  The 3-way switches are intended to control the light only.  The outlets should be always-on.  I left out grounds/amps/gauges for brevity. Thanks in advance.

[image: Circuit 1]

[image: Circuit 2]

Comment: No. The /3 cable to the 3-way switch is incorrect.  White must be used in this order of priority: Neutral *then* always-hot *then* traveler.  Here you are using black as always-hot and white as a traveler.  Swap em.

Answer (score 3):

**It's not to current code** because there's no neutral to switch #2 since you are not indicating /4 cable and blue wire as traveler which is needed for switch #2. Red and White travelers means no neutral to switch #2 and is not valid past NEC 2011 when neutrals at all switches were required (whether or not the present switch needs one.) So as an existing grandfathered circuit, it should work (if connected correctly to the switches) but it's not legal to **install** in most places that have adopted vaguely up  to date versions of code.

Switch #1 presumably has access to the neutral from the supply.

Comment: And as noted in Machavity's answer, the junctions either need to be in the box with the outlet/switch, or in a permanently accessible junction box other than that - usually in the box with the device is most sensible. Then there's box fill calculations for how big the boxes need to be based on number and size of wires.

Comment: That makes perfect sense, it was an older circuit, thank you.

Comment: As long as the first 3-way switch has vantage to see the whole room, neutral at the second is not required. The purpose is to support motion sensors.

Answer (score 2):

Electrically, this is correct. You're creating two branches in each one.

The catch is that those wire nuts have to live somewhere inside a junction box. In diagram #1, you can save a box by running to the outlet, then feeding your switch. In the second one, the normal way to handle this is to run them in series.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe. Maybe not. For wiring the hot & travelers to a 3-way switch, the important thing is the color of the screws, not their position on the switch.

The black screw is the hot, while the brass screws are the travelers and the green screw is ground.